# How to start curvy bracket at the end of the line (Shortcut) in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

For example:  `if(checkInputs(email, username, password|))`

If I finish type the word `password` and the cursor (`|`) is at that position.

Is there anyway to start a curvy bracket at the very end without have to press right arrow twice?

And what if I needed to put a `;` to finish the line. Is there a way through a shortcut to do it faster?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the "Complete statement" shortcut. This will add closing parentheses, brackets, semicolons, etc. By default it is bound to `Control + Shift + Enter` or `Command + Shift + Enter`.

Check the list of shortcuts here: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: It only adds semi colons for me.

Comment: Perhaps your code style settings do not require curly braces for single-line control-flow statements? I use the complete statement shortcut hundreds of times a day and it adds braces/parens/etc for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `end` button ([the one that says `end`](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Insertpad.svg/1200px-Insertpad.svg.png)).

Using `end` sends the cursor to the end of the line, and using `home` sends the cursor to the front of the line. It works no matter where in the line you are, assuming it isn't at the end of the line already (because that would of course not do anything because it's already there).

Also note that if there is a comment at the end of the actual code (still same line) it jumps to the end of the comment instead.

For mac it's different. It's the same idea (untested though, I don't have mac). There you press `Function + [Arrow left/arrow right]`

Comment: I only have home on my keyboard. I don't have the "end" button.

That's my notebook's keyboard 

https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1i.tKRpXXXXccXpXXq6xXFXXXH/New-US-Backlit-Keyboard-For-font-b-ASUS-b-font-font-b-ROG-b-font-font.jpg

Comment: CTRL+LEFT-ARROW is the closest you get in that case. It can skip blocks of text, but it has to be the same word (it can skip two parentheses with one press, but it can't skip a String with multiple words with one press). Can't find a way to replicate the `end` button functionality as a shortcut, so if you don't have end, this is the way to go